# Going crazy trying to install Quantstrat

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat

I am trying to install quanstrat. So far I have downloaded Rtools35 I am using R 3.5.1 when i use the code

```
  devtools::install_github("braverock/blotter")
```

I receive this error

```
   Downloading GitHub repo braverock/blotter@master
   Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
```

Here is the path

```
 Sys.getenv('PATH')
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.1\\bin\\x64;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ATI Technologies\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Users\\Jordan\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;"
```

Your help is much appreciated thank you! If there is a better alternative to quanstrat please let me know!

Comment: You need to have Rtools installed. RStudio should make it easy to install and use Rtools. Not sure why you would be having a problem if you have Rtools installed and RStudio knows about it. You may have problems if you installed Rtools somewhere RStudio is not looking for them.

Comment: Thanks alot @JoshuaUlrich if you have some time, could you help answer my question on using Shiny with Quantstrat. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146541/shiny-with-quantstrat

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY figured it out. You CAN NOT do this in Rstudio. You have to do it in R. Uhhh why did they make that so difficult?

Comment: If you are suggesting that the use of Rtools is restricted to R only and cannot be used from within RStudio (running R), then you are mistaken. Can you confirm that Rtools is in your `PATH` as seen in RStudio? Perhaps `strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")[[1]]` in RStudio, contrasting with the same command in "just R" to see if your environment variables are to blame for the behavior.